# Correct way to document type as function in epytext

Tags: python, epydoc

What is the correct way to specify a variable's type as a function or instancemethod in epytext?

I've seen this:

```
@type  cb: fn
```

and I've also seen this:

```
@type  cb: function or instancemethod
```

Comment: My guess is that there's no single "correct" way. Most likely there are only conventions. I doubt Epydoc itself imposes any restrictions. Certainly, it's preferable to be consistent (so you're not using `fn` in some places and `function` in other places). As for choosing a specific spelling, I'd personally go with `function` if it's supposed to be a function, or `instancemethod` if it's supposed to be an instance method. I'm not sure where a function or a *bound* instance method would be equally acceptable; and an *unbound* instance method is, for all intents and purposes, just a function.